# Ionic Xcode build, Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic2, ionic3

I know this has been posted about a million times but I still can't figure out what's going on.

This is an Ionic 3 project that already works and builds fine on Android. I am now trying to build it for iOS and I'm getting this error when building in Xcode. I already checked my `Link Binary With Libraries` build phase and there are no pod files in there. Also I am in the .xcworkspace file, not the .xcodeproj.

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error
    Linker command failed with exit code 1
```

When I build using `ionic cordova build ios` I get an error code 65 for build command xcodebuild.

Edit: After some more digging I think I found a more specific error, `Framework not found FileProvider for architecture x86_64`.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this error?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give an alternative here. That is you can use [**Ionic Package**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/package/) service.

> Ionic Packages makes it easy to build a native binary of your app in
>   the cloud. Perfect for developers using Windows that want to build iOS
>   apps.

*This lets you:*

- Send your packaged app to others
- Build your app for platforms not supported by your computer (e.g. iOS
  builds on Windows)
- Build .ipa and .apk files that you can submit to app stores

Comment: You should change your answer to link to Ionic Pro. The Ionic Cloud service you linked to is deprecated and should not be used anymore. That being said I did try building with Ionic Pro and I am having lots of different errors from that, so I'll keep trying to figure that out.

Comment: Yep, Done that.

Comment: Okay, I tried building with Ionic Pro and now I still get the exact same error there too.